# How to skip the processing of a file when datasource.notfound in Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

Power Query takes from a cell the path it should go for the source files.

I want to handle the situation when there are no files in that folder or when there isn't any text in the cell referring to the path. The goal is to skip the following steps (or maybe to cheat the next steps with an empty table) if the cell or the folder (DigitalCallPath) is empty.

I tried, among many things, the functions try... otherwise without any success.

This is how my code is:

```
let
    DigitalCallPath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DigitalCallPath"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
    Origen = Folder.Files(DigitalCallPath),
    #"Archivos ocultos filtrados1" = Table.SelectRows(Origen, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
    #"Invocar función personalizada1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Archivos ocultos filtrados1", "Transformar archivo (2)", each #"Transformar archivo (2)"([Content])),
    #"Columnas con nombre cambiado1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invocar función personalizada1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
    #"Otras columnas quitadas1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Columnas con nombre cambiado1", {"Source.Name", "Transformar archivo (2)"}),
    #"Columna de tabla expandida1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Otras columnas quitadas1", "Transformar archivo (2)", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transformar archivo (2)"(#"Archivo de ejemplo (2)"))),
    #"Tipo cambiado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Columna de tabla expandida1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Id. de la cuenta (NO modificar campo)", type text}, {"Nombre", type text}, {"Apellidos", type text}, {"a/o", type text}, {"Genero", type text}, {"Nº de Documento", Int64.Type}, {"Fecha de nacimiento", type any}, {"Correo electrónico", type text}, {"Teléfono Celular", Int64.Type}, {"Teléfono particular", type any}, {"Calle", type text}, {"Ciudad", type text}, {"Provincia", type text}, {"Código postal", Int64.Type}, {"Banco (Ver desplegable)", type text}, {"Tarjeta (Ver desplegable)", type any}, {"Nº de Tarjeta", type text}, {"Vencimiento", type date}, {"Recibo  (No modificar)", type any}, {"Descripción Fuente  (No modificar)", type any}, {"Descripción Origen  (Nombre del operador)", type text}, {"Fecha Ingreso", type date}, {"Comentarios", type text}, {"Monto Donacion", Int64.Type}, {"País  (No modificar)", type text}, {"Id. del propietario (No modificar)", type text}, {"Autoriza llamadas (No modificar)", type text}, {"Fecha de alta  (Dejarlo vacío)", type any}, {"Fuente (No modificar)", type text}, {"Autoriza envío postal", type text}, {"Correo electonico alternativo", type any}, {"Pack Fin de Año (Ver desplegable)", type text}, {"Relación con donante  (No modificar)", type text}, {"Tipo de direccion", type text}, {"Tipo de Documento", type text}, {"Welcome Pack (Ver desplegable)", type text}, {"Modalidad  ", type text}, {"Base", type text}}),
    #"Filas filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(#"Tipo cambiado", each ([Nombre] <> null)),
    #"Columnas con nombre cambiado" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filas filtradas",{{"Nombre", "Nombre"}, {"Apellidos", "Apellido"}, {"Genero", "Genero__c"}, {"Nº de Documento", "N_de_Documento__c"}, {"Fecha de nacimiento", "Birthdate"}, {"Correo electrónico", "Email"}, {"Teléfono Celular", "MobilePhone"}, {"Teléfono particular", "HomePhone"}, {"Calle", "MailingStreet"}, {"Código postal", "MailingPostalCode"}, {"Descripción Origen  (Nombre del operador)", "Descripci_n_Origen__c"}, {"Base", "Campaña"}, {"Monto Donacion", "Monto_Donacion__c"}, {"Fecha Ingreso", "Fecha_Ingreso__c"}, {"Banco (Ver desplegable)", "Entidad Bancaria"}, {"Tarjeta (Ver desplegable)", "Tipo de Tarjeta"}, {"Nº de Tarjeta", "Numero de Tarjeta"}, {"Ciudad", "MailingCity"}}),
    Fuente__c = Table.AddColumn(#"Columnas con nombre cambiado", "Fuente__c", each "Telemarketing"),
    Descripci_n_Fuente__c = Table.AddColumn(Fuente__c, "Descripci_n_Fuente__c", each "Digital Call"),
    #"Columnas quitadas" = Table.RemoveColumns(Descripci_n_Fuente__c,{"Id. de la cuenta (NO modificar campo)", "a/o", "Recibo  (No modificar)", "Descripción Fuente  (No modificar)", "Id. del propietario (No modificar)", "Autoriza llamadas (No modificar)", "Fecha de alta  (Dejarlo vacío)", "Autoriza envío postal", "Correo electonico alternativo", "Pack Fin de Año (Ver desplegable)", "Tipo de direccion", "Tipo de Documento", "Welcome Pack (Ver desplegable)", "Modalidad  ", "País  (No modificar)", "Fuente (No modificar)", "Relación con donante  (No modificar)"}),
    #"Columnas con nombre cambiado2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Columnas quitadas",{{"Vencimiento", "Vencimiento__c"}, {"Comentarios", "Comentarios__c"}})
in
    #"Columnas con nombre cambiado2"
```

Could you please help me out with this?

I've been trying several ways, but I cannot find the way to write in the code, "if the folder is empty, use this empty table"

I've been trying two functions:

- IF...Then...Else
- Try...Otherwise

  ```
  let
      DigitalCallPath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DigitalCallPath"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
      Origen = Folder.Files(DigitalCallPath),
      // Check if DigitalCallPath is null or empty
      if DigitalCallPath = null or DigitalCallPath = "" then
          // Return immediately if DigitalCallPath is null or empty
          return;
      else
      // Continue with the rest of the instructions
          #"Archivos ocultos filtrados1" = Table.SelectRows(Origen, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
  ```

The empty table that should be something like:

```
#table({"Id. de la cuenta (NO modificar campo)",    "Nombre",   "Apellidos",    "a/o",  "Genero",   "Nº de Documento",  "Fecha de nacimiento",  "Correo electrónico",   "Teléfono Celular", "Teléfono particular",  "Calle",    "Ciudad",   "Provincia",    "Código postal",    "Banco (Ver desplegable)",  "Tarjeta (Ver desplegable)",    "Nº de Tarjeta",    "Vencimiento",  "Recibo  (No modificar)",   "Descripción Fuente  (No modificar)",   "Descripción Origen  (Nombre del operador)",    "Fecha Ingreso",    "Comentarios",  "Monto Donacion",   "País  (No modificar)", "Id. del propietario (No modificar)",   "Autoriza llamadas (No modificar)", "Fecha de alta  (Dejarlo vacío)",   "Fuente (No modificar)",    "Autoriza envío postal",    "Correo electonico alternativo",    "Pack Fin de Año (Ver desplegable)",    "Relación con donante  (No modificar)", "Tipo de direccion",    "Tipo de Documento",    "Welcome Pack (Ver desplegable)",   "Modalidad  ",  "Base"}, {})
```

Many many thanks for your support,
Julian

Comment: So... if `Folder.Files(DataAcesPath)` fails to be evaluated correctly, use your empty table to define `Origen`, is that it?

Comment: Yes... the idea is something like that...

Comment: In Power query, the syntax is **not** `try Origen = ... otherwise Origen = ....`. Instead, it is `Origen = (try ... otherwise ....)`. Can you try this way (with a correct `#table` function because you forgot to add `{}` as its second parameter)

Comment: You seem to have changed the code provided in the question several times since I started looking at it, that makes it super hard for me to answer... Please provide your current working code (without the empty table) if you still cannot insert it in the right spot.

Comment: First of all: Thanks you a lot! 
I'm so sorry, i'm not used to comment this things!! 
Do you suggest trying?:
`Origen = (try Folder.Files(DigitalCallPath) otherwise #table({"Id. de la cuenta (NO modificar campo)", ... ,{})) `

Comment: That is one of the possibilities. You can also put all the next steps in the `try` part. That is a way to (quote/unquote) "stop" the formula but I cannot demonstrate without your full code, or at least the next 1 or 2 steps.

Comment: @Atmo I've just added the full code... all your advices were a great improved to solve the issue but still doesn't work... Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Except for the `#"Transformar archivo (2)"` that you may have defined elsewhere, the code  you posted allowed me to provide an answer. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
let DigitalCallPath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DigitalCallPath"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
ztable = #table({"Id. de la cuenta (NO modificar campo)",    "Nombre",   "Apellidos",    "a/o",  "Genero",   "Nº de Documento",  "Fecha de nacimiento",  "Correo electrónico",   "Teléfono Celular", "Teléfono particular",  "Calle",    "Ciudad",   "Provincia",    "Código postal",    "Banco (Ver desplegable)",  "Tarjeta (Ver desplegable)",    "Nº de Tarjeta",    "Vencimiento",  "Recibo  (No modificar)",   "Descripción Fuente  (No modificar)",   "Descripción Origen  (Nombre del operador)",    "Fecha Ingreso",    "Comentarios",  "Monto Donacion",   "País  (No modificar)", "Id. del propietario (No modificar)",   "Autoriza llamadas (No modificar)", "Fecha de alta  (Dejarlo vacío)",   "Fuente (No modificar)",    "Autoriza envío postal",    "Correo electonico alternativo",    "Pack Fin de Año (Ver desplegable)",    "Relación con donante  (No modificar)", "Tipo de direccion",    "Tipo de Documento",    "Welcome Pack (Ver desplegable)",   "Modalidad  ",  "Base"},{}),
Origen =   Folder.Files(DigitalCallPath),
Output = if (try Table.RowCount(Origen) otherwise 0) =0 then ztable else Table.SelectRows(Origen, each [Attributes] <> true)
in Output
```

Comment: No, i couldn't make the code continue after the output

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach is to nest your `let ... in ...` in such a way it skips the time-consuming calculation.

I cannot check the final result (the language of your variables and columns is a true barrier to understand the steps + you may have defined `#"Transformar archivo (2)"` separately) but it should consist in the steps:

1. Define a table with no records (= empty table) with all the columns you expect in your final result.
   There is no need to define an `EmptyTable` variable, however, I found it would result in a clearer explanation for you if I did it that way.
2. For `Origen`, surround `Folder.Files(...)` with a `try ... otherwise ...` to return an empty table if the folder does not exist.
   Note that the exception will not be caught unless you use `Table.Buffer`. I am certain this is a bug and it may not exist in a more recent version of Excel than the one I am using but as it is a possibility, I suggest you keep it that way.
3. Make a `if Table.isEmpty(Origen) then EmptyTable else (<lengthy calculation>)` in order to have a structure to skip calculation if it falls into the `else` part.

Which looks like this:

```
let
    /* Define an empty table with the same columns as what is expected in the final result. */
    EmptyTable = #table({"Add the columns of final variable Columnas con nombre cambiado2 here"}, {}),
    DigitalCallPath = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DigitalCallPath"]}[Content][Column1]{0},
    /* Origen will be empty if there is no file (obviously) or if the folder does not exist. */
    Origen = try Table.Buffer(Folder.Files(DigitalCallPath)) otherwise #table({"Empty table" }, {}),
    result = if Table.IsEmpty(Origen) then EmptyTable else (
/* If Origen is empty, all of this is skipped. */
    let
        #"Archivos ocultos filtrados1" = Table.SelectRows(Origen, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true),
        #"Invocar función personalizada1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Archivos ocultos filtrados1", "Transformar archivo (2)", each #"Transformar archivo (2)"([Content])),
        #"Columnas con nombre cambiado1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Invocar función personalizada1", {"Name", "Source.Name"}),
        #"Otras columnas quitadas1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Columnas con nombre cambiado1", {"Source.Name", "Transformar archivo (2)"}),
        #"Columna de tabla expandida1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Otras columnas quitadas1", "Transformar archivo (2)", Table.ColumnNames(#"Transformar archivo (2)"(#"Archivo de ejemplo (2)"))),
        #"Tipo cambiado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Columna de tabla expandida1",{{"Source.Name", type text}, {"Id. de la cuenta (NO modificar campo)", type text}, {"Nombre", type text}, {"Apellidos", type text}, {"a/o", type text}, {"Genero", type text}, {"Nº de Documento", Int64.Type}, {"Fecha de nacimiento", type any}, {"Correo electrónico", type text}, {"Teléfono Celular", Int64.Type}, {"Teléfono particular", type any}, {"Calle", type text}, {"Ciudad", type text}, {"Provincia", type text}, {"Código postal", Int64.Type}, {"Banco (Ver desplegable)", type text}, {"Tarjeta (Ver desplegable)", type any}, {"Nº de Tarjeta", type text}, {"Vencimiento", type date}, {"Recibo  (No modificar)", type any}, {"Descripción Fuente  (No modificar)", type any}, {"Descripción Origen  (Nombre del operador)", type text}, {"Fecha Ingreso", type date}, {"Comentarios", type text}, {"Monto Donacion", Int64.Type}, {"País  (No modificar)", type text}, {"Id. del propietario (No modificar)", type text}, {"Autoriza llamadas (No modificar)", type text}, {"Fecha de alta  (Dejarlo vacío)", type any}, {"Fuente (No modificar)", type text}, {"Autoriza envío postal", type text}, {"Correo electonico alternativo", type any}, {"Pack Fin de Año (Ver desplegable)", type text}, {"Relación con donante  (No modificar)", type text}, {"Tipo de direccion", type text}, {"Tipo de Documento", type text}, {"Welcome Pack (Ver desplegable)", type text}, {"Modalidad  ", type text}, {"Base", type text}}),
        #"Filas filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(#"Tipo cambiado", each ([Nombre] <> null)),
        #"Columnas con nombre cambiado" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filas filtradas",{{"Nombre", "Nombre"}, {"Apellidos", "Apellido"}, {"Genero", "Genero__c"}, {"Nº de Documento", "N_de_Documento__c"}, {"Fecha de nacimiento", "Birthdate"}, {"Correo electrónico", "Email"}, {"Teléfono Celular", "MobilePhone"}, {"Teléfono particular", "HomePhone"}, {"Calle", "MailingStreet"}, {"Código postal", "MailingPostalCode"}, {"Descripción Origen  (Nombre del operador)", "Descripci_n_Origen__c"}, {"Base", "Campaña"}, {"Monto Donacion", "Monto_Donacion__c"}, {"Fecha Ingreso", "Fecha_Ingreso__c"}, {"Banco (Ver desplegable)", "Entidad Bancaria"}, {"Tarjeta (Ver desplegable)", "Tipo de Tarjeta"}, {"Nº de Tarjeta", "Numero de Tarjeta"}, {"Ciudad", "MailingCity"}}),
        Fuente__c = Table.AddColumn(#"Columnas con nombre cambiado", "Fuente__c", each "Telemarketing"),
        Descripci_n_Fuente__c = Table.AddColumn(Fuente__c, "Descripci_n_Fuente__c", each "Digital Call"),
        #"Columnas quitadas" = Table.RemoveColumns(Descripci_n_Fuente__c,{"Id. de la cuenta (NO modificar campo)", "a/o", "Recibo  (No modificar)", "Descripción Fuente  (No modificar)", "Id. del propietario (No modificar)", "Autoriza llamadas (No modificar)", "Fecha de alta  (Dejarlo vacío)", "Autoriza envío postal", "Correo electonico alternativo", "Pack Fin de Año (Ver desplegable)", "Tipo de direccion", "Tipo de Documento", "Welcome Pack (Ver desplegable)", "Modalidad  ", "País  (No modificar)", "Fuente (No modificar)", "Relación con donante  (No modificar)"}),
        #"Columnas con nombre cambiado2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Columnas quitadas",{{"Vencimiento", "Vencimiento__c"}, {"Comentarios", "Comentarios__c"}})
    in
        #"Columnas con nombre cambiado2"
    )
in
    result
```

As long as you ensure the code stays clear, you can create any number of `let ... in ...` structures like this.
Alternatively, you can define a function to do all the complicated work so you can write:

```
result = if Table.IsEmpty(Origen) then EmptyTable else MyFunction(Origen)
```